# Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture. - Resource file sharing problem

Tags: c#, silverlight, shared-libraries, resx

I have a normal class library. Recently, I localized this class library.

I also have another Silverlight class library, Which is basically a **linked file project**

```
<Link>Reports\Reports.cs</Link>
```

In that, I have included the same resx file as link reference as I done for other files. While running, it throws the following exception.

```
Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  
Make sure "BCL.Resources.BCLNamespace.resources" was correctly embedded
 or linked into assembly "SilverlightBCL" at compile time, or that all the 
 satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping the Default namespace in Assembly2 (SilverlightBCL) as same as Assembly1 (BCL) fixes this issue. 
Thanks all :)

Comment: I had the same issue, changing both projects properties to use the same default namespace worked.

Answer (score 1):

In the [Filename].Designer.cs , it could be one of the following:

- the Namespace

  ```
  namespace Company.Dept.MyApp.Resource {
      // Your code here.
  }
  ```
- ResourceManager

  ```
  new global::System.Resources.ResourceManager(
      "Company.Dept.MyApp.Resource.Templates", 
      typeof(Templates).Assembly);
  ```

Comment: What is the problem according to you? Both these are OK in my project and it still fails